# facebook like option to display image and description on the facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, magento, facebook-like

Is it possible to implement the facebook like action in such a way that i want to display the title, image and description in the users wall.

I used the default facebook like option http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

and i set the open graph tags as

```
`<meta property="og:type" content="website" /><meta property="og:title" content="Michael Miller Fabrics" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/dec2011_release_homepage.jpg" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://wwww.mywebsite.com/" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="My site name" /><meta property="og:description" content="A short description about the site" />`
```

But when i click the like link, only the default facebook logo and default logo are displayed on my wall.

Anyone know what I am missing here. I want to set the facebook like option for my website products such that whenever a user clicks the like link of a particular product, the image and name of the product with its description need to be displayed on the facebook wall. currently the default image and title for the home page is displayed even if I changed the og:image  and og:title values. how to dynamically display the image and description of each product on the facebook wall when a user clicks the facebook like link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the facebook debugger tool to see in advance what their **scraper** gets.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

it will also let you know of problems/warnings you have in the open graph protocol.

Comment: I have verified with this debugger tool and there are no errors or inferred properties.

Comment: If the debugger gets the right data then it should work when someone likes the page (since the same action is taking place, where facebook "crawls" your page, unless they have the response cached).  Is the image the only thing that does not work well? or other open graph meta data?  also, are you by any chance testing things on a local machine?

Comment: The image as well as the other meta data don't work well. I am testing on my development server, not a local machine. I have noticed one interesting thing, such that the image and other meta data works well if I run the debugger. Otherwise it posts the previous meta data items.

Comment: what do you mean by "previous meta data items"? Are you talking about a caching problem?